# Method getText() must be called from UI Thread from eclipse project to android studio

Tags: android

I try to import my project to android studio from eclipse and after fix some problem i got this one, need help please...
[ImageProbelmHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llqDG.jpg)

here is my code :
if anything else you need to help fix this, just comment below

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.inarts.mobile.merch.md.info.AppInfo;
import com.inarts.mobile.merch.md.info.UserInfo;
import com.inarts.rest.RequestMethod;
import com.inarts.rest.RestClient;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public String targetUrl = "";
    public String userName = "";
    public String userUsername = "";
    public String userPassword = "";
    public boolean userSaveCB = false;
    public static Context ctx;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ctx = this.getApplicationContext();
        targetUrl = Config.getEndPointUrl() + "/login.json";

        // Log.i("ncdebug","Ma, i'm in login: "+getLoginState());
        TextView tvcopyright = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_copyright);
        tvcopyright.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

        EditText tvUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_user_txt);
        EditText tvPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_pass_txt);
        CheckBox cbSavePassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.main_save_cb);

        if (isSavePassword()) {
            tvUsername.setText(getSavedUsername());
            tvPassword.setText(getSavedPassword());
            cbSavePassword.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            cbSavePassword.setChecked(false);
        }

        if (getLoginState()) {
            Log.i("ncdebug", "I am logged in");
            goToMainActivity();
        } else {
            // intent_depan();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Keluar").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_exit);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        return;
    }

    public void click_login(View view) {
        EditText user_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_user_txt);
        EditText pass_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_pass_txt);
        if (user_txt.getText().toString().equals(AppInfo.adminName)
                && pass_txt.getText().toString().equals(AppInfo.adminPass)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, StoreAddGeoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            new AuthenticateTask().execute(targetUrl);
        }

    }

    public void goToMainActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void saveLoginState() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("user_name", userName);
        editor.putString("user_username", userUsername);
        editor.putString("user_password", userPassword);
        editor.putBoolean("loginState", true);

        CheckBox cbSavePassword = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.main_save_cb);
        if (cbSavePassword.isChecked()) {
            editor.putBoolean("isSavePassword", true);
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean("isSavePassword", false);
        }

        UserInfo.username = userUsername;
        UserInfo.name = userName;
        UserInfo.loginstatus = true;

        editor.commit();
    }

    public boolean isSavePassword() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        boolean stat = settings.getBoolean("isSavePassword", false);

        return stat;
    }

    public String getSavedUsername() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        return settings.getString("user_username", "");
    }

    public String getSavedPassword() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        return settings.getString("user_password", "");
    }

    public boolean getLoginState() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        UserInfo.username = settings.getString("user_username", "");
        UserInfo.name = settings.getString("user_name", "");

        boolean stat = settings.getBoolean("loginState", false);
        UserInfo.loginstatus = stat;

        return stat;
    }

    private class AuthenticateTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Loading...",
                    true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            RestClient client = new RestClient(targetUrl);

            EditText user_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_user_txt);
            EditText pass_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_pass_txt);

            userUsername = user_txt.getText().toString();
            userPassword = pass_txt.getText().toString();

            client.AddParam("username", user_txt.getText().toString());
            client.AddParam("password", pass_txt.getText().toString());

            try {
                client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
                return client.getResponse();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String Result) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (Result != null) {
                parseJson(Result);
            } else {
                // intent_depan();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx,
                        "Login Failed, Connection Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        public void parseJson(String s) {
            try {
                JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(s);
                String stat = jobj.getString("stat");
                //
                // Log.i("json result", "string result " + s1);
                if (stat.equals("failed")) {
                    String msg = jobj.getString("msg");
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    userName = jobj.getString("name");
                    // Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, userName,
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    saveLoginState();

                    goToMainActivity();
                }

                /*
                 * if (s1 == "success") { intent_depan(); } else {
                 * intent_depan(); }
                 */
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to get the text fron any of your Edittext in onPreExecute() method of asyncTask. As this action is also considered as UI interference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `doInBackground` method does not run on the UI thread. You can get the data from the `TextView` before calling the `AsyncTask` and pass the data into the `execute` method of the `AsyncTask`.

When you call your `AsyncTask`,

```
userUsername = user_txt.getText().toString();
userPassword = pass_txt.getText().toString();

new AuthenticateTask().execute(targetUrl, userUsername, userPassword);
```

The `params` argument holds the arguments passed to the `execute` method.

Inside `doInBackground`,

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    RestClient client = new RestClient(params[0]);

    client.AddParam("username", params[1]);
    client.AddParam("password", params[2]);

    ...
}
```

Comment: my problem now {org.json.JSONException: Value <h1>404 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject} what's wrong with this ?

Comment: Check your server response. Seems like some error with it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code

```
        EditText user_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_user_txt);
        EditText pass_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_pass_txt);

        userUsername = user_txt.getText().toString();
        userPassword = pass_txt.getText().toString();
```

with this

```
        final EditText user_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_user_txt);
        final EditText pass_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_pass_txt);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                userUsername = user_txt.getText().toString();
                userPassword = pass_txt.getText().toString();
            }
        });
```

in doInBackground() method of AuthenticateTask AsyncTask class.
I hope this will help you.
All the best

Answer (score 0):

```
onPreExecute()    // - Runs on UI Thread
doInBackground()  // - Runs in background so don't do UI operations here
onPostExceute()   // - Runs on UI Thread after completion of Network/long operations
```

Update your code like this

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Loading...",
            true);
    EditText user_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_user_txt);
    EditText pass_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_pass_txt);

    userUsername = user_txt.getText().toString();
    userPassword = pass_txt.getText().toString();
}

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        RestClient client = new RestClient(targetUrl);

        client.AddParam(username);
        client.AddParam(password);

        try {
            client.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
            return client.getResponse();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.ctx, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

EditText.gettext need to run on UIthread so you can change this method

```
    public void click_login(View view) {
        EditText user_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_user_txt);
        EditText pass_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_pass_txt);
        //Add this two line
        userUsername = user_txt.getText().toString();
        userPassword = pass_txt.getText().toString();

if (userUsername.equals(AppInfo.adminName)
                && userPassword.equals(AppInfo.adminPass)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, StoreAddGeoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            new AuthenticateTask().execute(targetUrl);
        }

    }
```

//Don't forget change here (in doingbackground)

```
         //Remove these 4 lines. 
       // EditText user_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_user_txt);
       //EditText pass_txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_pass_txt);
       //  userUsername = user_txt.getText().toString();
       //  userPassword = pass_txt.getText().toString();

        client.AddParam("username", userUsername);
        client.AddParam("password", userPassword);
```